# ¿Cómo extraer la información de una tabla de SQL Server a Excel por medio de Python?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, python-3.x, python-requests

me gustaría extraer la información de una tabla de SQL Server a un Excel por medio de Python, tengo la siguiente tabla:

Tabla:

```
SELECT * FROM Tabla1
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Adicional, en Python estoy realizando lo siguiente, pero por alguna razón no se carga la info en el Excel:

```
USUARIO_SQL_ORIGEN = ''
PASSWORD_USUARIO_SQL_ORIGEN = ''
SERVIDOR_SQL_ORIGEN = '' 
BASE_DATOS_SQL_ORIGEN = ''

# Creación de la conexión

CADENA_DE_CONEXION_ORIGEN = f"mssql+pyodbc://{USUARIO_SQL_ORIGEN}: 
{PASSWORD_USUARIO_SQL_ORIGEN}@{SERVIDOR_SQL_ORIGEN}/{BASE_DATOS_SQL_ORIGEN}? 
driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server"

#CREA CONEXIONES

conexion = create_engine(CADENA_DE_CONEXION_ORIGEN,echo=False)
Consulta_Pestana_1 = "SELECT * FROM Tabla1 "

# Conversión de las consultas a Data Frames (DF) 

DF_Pestana_1 = pd.read_sql_query(sql=text(Consulta_Pestana_1), con=conexion.connect())
```

Hasta acá no tengo ningún problema, pero cuando quiero extraer la información, me sale un error.

```
actualizar_IPT = load_workbook("C:/Users/Documents/Informacion.xlsx")
actualizacion = actualizar_IPT['Hoja1']
actualizacion['Hoja1'] = DF_Pestana_1

actualizar_IFT.save("Informacion.xlsx")
```

El error que me sale, es el siguiente: "ValueError: Hoja1 is not a valid coordinate or range"

Existe la manera de actualizar el archivo??

Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prueba con la libreria csv, utiliza una funcion similar a esta para exportar un archivo excel con los datos que necesitas

```
def exportar(self):
self.ruta_exportar = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(title = "ExportarArchivo", initialdir = "/home/user/escritorio/", filetypes = (('Archivo CSV', '.csv'), ('Archivo Excel', '.xls')))
    conn = pymssql.connect( host=r'test\SQLEXPRESS', user=r'sa', password='admin', database='test') 
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT Col1, Col2, Col3 FROM nombretabla')
    with open(self.ruta_exportar, mode = "w", encoding = 'utf-8') as micsv:   
        exportador = csv.writer(micsv)
        exportador.writerow(['Col1', 'col2', 'col3'])   
        exportador.writerows(cursor)
    conn.close()
    messagebox.showinfo(title = "Exportador", message = "Datos Exportados Correctamente")
```